# Does extent report community edition has support for extentx server

Tags: extentreports, extent

I am trying to use the extent report with TestNG framework.

I am referring the following page to configure TestNG for extent report. 
http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/2/java/#testng-example

This works fine after few changes in the code, and I am able to see the HTML report generated in the directory I have configured.

However, I am not able to figure out how to upload these result to extentx server.

I have configured the server as mentioned below. 
http://extentreports.com/docs/extentx/

the problem is, there is no **method x** on extent object.

```
private void init() {
    ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(OUTPUT_FOLDER + FILE_NAME);
    htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("ExtentReports - Created by TestNG Listener");
    htmlReporter.config().setReportName("ExtentReports - Created by TestNG Listener");
    htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.BOTTOM);
    htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);

    extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
    extent.setReportUsesManualConfiguration(true);
    extent.x("loclahost", "1337"); //No Such Method 
}
```

I am using latest version of extent report 3.0.3

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ExtentXReporter  extentxReporter = new ExtentXReporter("localhost", 27017);
            extentxReporter.config().setProjectName(suites.get(0).getName());
extentxReporter.config().setReportName("test");
//then add extentx
extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter,extentxReporter);
```

You also need to have the mongodb running on localhost by default port is 27017

Answer (score -1):

```
ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(OUTPUT_FOLDER + FILE_NAME);

ExtentXReporter extentxReporter = new ExtentXReporter("mongodb-host", mongodb-port);

ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();

extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter,extentxReporter);
```

Comment: please try to add some description.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)